# How to enable pkg_add for OpenBSD

Tags: package-management, git, openbsd

I installed and run OpenBSD and I wanted to install git but there were no repositories for OpenBSD. What should I do if I want to install some programs with pkg_add?

Comment: The [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq15.html#Easy) suggests setting the `PKG_PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On 6.0 and below, add a mirror to the file `/etc/pkg.conf`:

```
installpath = http://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.9/packages/amd64/
```

On 6.1 and later, use the file `/etc/installurl`:

```
https://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/
```

Comment: I did but when I try to to add with `pkg_add` it says the repo is empty.

Comment: Can you run `unset PKG_PATH && pkg_info -Q git` as root?

Comment: It says `error...is empty...`

Comment: Run this command: `ftp http://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/5.9/packages/amd64/SHA256` . Works?

Comment: No because it seems that my OpenBSD is offline and that I must enable networking first. I'm running it in virtualbox. Looks like I must configure `etc/hostname.iwn0`

Comment: Show me the output of :`ifconfig | grep '^[a-z]' | cut -d' ' -f1`

Comment: `lo0:\nem0\nenc0:\npflog0:\n`

Comment: Run as root: `echo dhcp > /etc/hostname.em0` and reboot the system.

Comment: It doesn't work. I try it with 6.0 and there is no git to be installed.

Comment: _"can't resolve curl-7.49.0"_ is what it says

Comment: Run this as root: `echo 'installpath = http://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/6.0/packages/amd64/' > /etc/pkg.conf`. And this: `unset PKG_PATH; pkg_delete -X; pkg_add git`.

Comment: Finally I succeeded with 6.1 and `/etc/installurl`

Answer (score 3):

You have to add one or more mirrors to your **/etc/pkg.conf**. You can add multiple mirrors by using the **+=** notation.

```
installpath = http://ftp5.eu.openbsd.org/ftp/pub/OpenBSD/%c/packages/%a/
installpath += http://ftp2.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/%c/packages/%a/
```

**%c** and **%a** are variables that get replaced by the release and the architecture of your installation. That way you don't have to upgrade your config file after every release.